# Using Swagger Apikey the Token is correct but I get Error 401

Tags: api-key

I have applied an authorization to all my endpoints and controllers i have applied log in and register in swagger the log in generates tokens to use for authentication but the issue comes when i try to use the token to get acess to use get, post , put and delete methods I get an error 401.

I have provided my json, program.cs and AuthenticationController.cs

```
using EcoPower.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
//using Auth_Identity_Login.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
//up above to remove
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.OpenApi;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using EcoPower.Data;
using EcoPower;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EcoPower.Middleware;
using AspNetCore.Authentication.ApiKey;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;





var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EcoPowerContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("easystring") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'EcoPowerContext' not found.")));






// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
//builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


// For Identity  
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EcoPowerContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
// Adding Authentication  
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };

    // Add event handler for OnAuthenticationFailed
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Exception);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // Apply JWT authentication
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});



// Add configuration from appsettings.json
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Api Key Auth", Version = "v1" });
    var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme//c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
            Name = "Authorization",
            Description = "Enter 'Bearer {token}'",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "Jwt"

    };
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securityScheme);
    // Specify your API key here
    //const string apiKeyValue = "your-secret-api-key";
    // Require the Bearer token for all API operations
    var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    };

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirement);
});



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebApplication16");
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}






app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};



app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast");





//app.Register();

//app.UseAuthorization();
//app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyAuthentication>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

IConfiguration configuration = app.Configuration;
IWebHostEnvironment environment = app.Environment;
//app.AuthenticationController();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapCustomerEndpoints();

app.MapSalesOrderDetailEndpoints();

app.MapSalesLTProductEndpoints();



app.Run();

internal record WeatherForecast(DateTime Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}

//authentication code
```

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EcoPowerContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EcoPower.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Jwt": {
    "ValidAudience": "http://localhost:7246",
    "ValidIssuer": "http://localhost:7246",
    "Secret": "ByYM000OLlMQG6VVVp1OH7Xzyr7gHuw1qvUC5dcGt3SNM",
    "Issuer": "Issuer",
    "Audience": "Audience",
    "Key": "bd1a1ccf8095037f361a4d351e7c0de65f0776bfc2f478ea8d312c763bb6caca"
  }

}
```

```
using EcoPower.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace EcoPower.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]


    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AuthenticationController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
            if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                };

                foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                {
                    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                }

                var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Secret"]));

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"],
                    audience: _configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"],
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                    claims: authClaims,
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                    );
                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
        {
            var userExists = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
            if (userExists != null)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });

            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                UserName = model.Username
            };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });

            return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });

            [HttpPost]
            [Route("register-admin")]
            async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAdmin([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
            {
                var userExists = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
                if (userExists != null)
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });

                ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Email = model.Email,
                    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    UserName = model.Username
                };
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });

                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.Admin));
                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.User));

                if (await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
                {
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Admin);
                }

                return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });
            }



        }

        
    }   
}
```

I tried checking if the token was incorrect but it was correct. i even tried to check if there was somthing wrong with my code but im struggling to find what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 Unauthorized error when using a JWT token for authentication in your ASP.NET Core Web API can occur for several reasons.
It can include Check Token Validity, Verify Token Configuration, Authorization Attribute and a lot more try  identify the root cause of the 401 Unauthorized error first and then you should be able to find a solution only then.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).